# Kendo React Dropdowns problem after upgraded to 4.7.0

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown

please have someone with the same problem?
./node_modules/@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns/dist/es/DropDownTree/DropDownTree.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@progress/kendo-react-treeview' in '/ui/node_modules/@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns/dist/es/DropDownTree'

I'm using the latest version 4.7.0. It happened after upgraded.

Many thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Can be resolved adding "@progress/kendo-react-treeview": "^4.13.0", in package json file